# Vba to import a sub-portion of a hugh csv file into excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import

I have a csv file that has approx 600 fields and approx 100k of rows, i would like to import only select fields and only certian rows where a select set of fields match a certain set of criteria into an existing excel worksheet tab

I attempted to use ms query within excel but it stops at 255 columns, i can import the whole file in excel 2010 (250m) but it is a memory hog and by the time i remove the unneeded fields and rows it locks up my computer.

I would like to kick the import process off with an excel vba macro. I have all the front end code of file selection, etc.... But need some assistance in the text read query convert to excel area of vba

Any assitance would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

For that many records you would be better off importing the .csv into Microsoft Access, indexing some fields, writing a query that contains only what you want, and then exporting to Excel from the query.

If you really need an Excel-only solution, do the following:

1. Open up the VBA editor.  Navigate to Tools -> References.  Select the most recent ActiveX Data Objects Library.  (ADO for short).  On my XP machine running Excel 2003, it's version 2.8.
2. Create a module if you don't have one already.  Or create one anyway to contain the code at the bottom of this post.
3. In any blank worksheet paste the following values starting at cell A1:

SELECT  Field1, Field2
FROM    C:\Path\To\file.csv
WHERE   Field1 = 'foo'
ORDER BY    Field2

(Formatting issues here.  `select` `from`, etc should each be in their own row in col A for reference.  The other stuff are the important bits and should go in column B.)

Amend the input fields as appropriate for your filename and query requirements, then run the`getCsv()` subroutine.  It will put the results in a QueryTable object starting at cell C6.

I personally hate QueryTables but the `.CopyFromRecordset` method I prefer to use with ADO doesn't give you field names.  I left the code for that method in, commented out, so you can investigate that way.  If you use it, you can get rid of the call to `deleteQueryTables()` because it's a really ugly hack, it deletes whole columns which you may not like, etc.

Happy coding.

```
Option Explicit
Function ExtractFileName(filespec) As String
'   Returns a filename from a filespec
    Dim x As Variant
    x = Split(filespec, Application.PathSeparator)
    ExtractFileName = x(UBound(x))
End Function
Function ExtractPathName(filespec) As String
'   Returns the path from a filespec
    Dim x As Variant
    x = Split(filespec, Application.PathSeparator)
    ReDim Preserve x(0 To UBound(x) - 1)
    ExtractPathName = Join(x, Application.PathSeparator) & Application.PathSeparator
End Function
Sub getCsv()
    Dim cnCsv As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rsCsv As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strSelect As String
    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim strOrderBy As String
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim qtData As QueryTable

    strSelect = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value
    strFileName = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value
    strWhere = ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value
    strOrderBy = ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value

    strSql = "SELECT " & strSelect
    strSql = strSql & vbCrLf & "FROM " & ExtractFileName(strFileName)
    If strWhere <> "" Then strSql = strSql & vbCrLf & "WHERE " & strWhere
    If strOrderBy <> "" Then strSql = strSql & vbCrLf & "ORDER BY " & strOrderBy

    With cnCsv
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ExtractPathName(strFileName) & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=yes;FMT=Delimited(,)"";Persist Security Info=False"
        .Open
    End With

    rsCsv.Open strSql, cnCsv, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
    'ActiveSheet.Range("C6").CopyFromRecordset rsCsv

    Call deleteQueryTables
    Set qtData = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(rsCsv, ActiveSheet.Range("C6"))
    qtData.Refresh

    rsCsv.Close
    Set rsCsv = Nothing
    cnCsv.Close
    Set cnCsv = Nothing
End Sub
Sub deleteQueryTables()
    On Error Resume Next
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim qtName As String
    Dim nName As Name
    For Each qt In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
        qtName = qt.Name
        qt.Delete
        For Each nName In Names
            If InStr(1, nName.Name, qtName) > 0 Then
                Range(nName.Name).EntireColumn.Delete
                nName.Delete
            End If
        Next nName
    Next qt

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks guys for the great suggestions. I will attempt it as we speak. I attempted to do it in Access 2010 but hit the 255 column limitation. otherwise I would have wrote an SQL in Access. (would have been easy) :)

Comment: Thanks again, I will let everyone know how I made out.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your input file extracting the lines that conform to your criteria. The following code uses the split function on each line of the CSV file to separate the fields and then checks to see if it matches the required criteria. If all the criteria match then selected fields are saved in a new CSV file then you can just open the smaller file. You will need to set the microsoft scripting runtime reference in the VBA editor for this to work.

This method should use little memory as it processes 1 line at a time, I tested it on data of 600 fields and 100000 lines and it took about 45 seconds to process the file with no noticable increase in RAM usage in windows task manager. It is CPU intensive and the time taken would increase as the complexity data, conditions and the number of fields copied increases.

If you prefer to write directly to an existing sheet this can be easily acheived, but you would have to rememove any old data there first.

```
Sub Extract()

Dim fileHandleInput As Scripting.TextStream
Dim fileHandleExtract As Scripting.TextStream
Dim fsoObject As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim sPath As String
Dim sFilenameExtract As String
Dim sFilenameInput As String
Dim myVariant As Variant
Dim bParse As Boolean   'To check if the line should be written

sFilenameExtract = "Exctract1.CSV"
sFilenameInput = "Input.CSV"

Set fsoObject = New FileSystemObject

sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

'Check if this works ie overwrites existing file
If fsoObject.FileExists(sPath & sFilenameExtract) Then
    Set fileHandleExtract = fsoObject.OpenTextFile(sPath & sFilenameExtract, ForWriting)
Else
    Set fileHandleExtract = fsoObject.CreateTextFile((sPath & sFilenameExtract), True)
End If

Set fileHandleInput = fsoObject.OpenTextFile(sPath & sFilenameInput, ForReading)


'extracting headers for selected fields in this case the 1st, 2nd and 124th fields
myVariant = Split(fileHandleInput.ReadLine, ",")
fileHandleExtract.WriteLine (myVariant(0) & "," & _
                             myVariant(1) & "," & _
                             myVariant(123))

'Parse each line (row) of the inputfile
Do While Not fileHandleInput.AtEndOfStream
    myVariant = Split(fileHandleInput.ReadLine, ",")

    'Set bParse initially to true
    bParse = True

    'Check if the first element is greater than 123
    If Not myVariant(0) > 123 Then bParse = False

    'Check if second element is one of allowed values
    'Trim used to remove pesky leading or lagging values when checking
    Select Case Trim(myVariant(1))

    Case "Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Black"
    'Do nothing as value found

    Case Else
        bParse = False  'As wasn't a value in the condition
    End Select

    'If the conditions were met by the line then write specific fields to extract file
    If bParse Then
        fileHandleExtract.WriteLine (myVariant(0) & "," & _
                                     myVariant(1) & "," & _
                                     myVariant(123))
    End If

Loop

'close files and cleanup
fileHandleExtract.Close
fileHandleInput.Close

Set fileHandleExtract = Nothing
Set fileHandleInput = Nothing
Set fsoObject = Nothing

End Sub
```